# What is wrong with my bush bean tendergreen leaves?

Tags: beans, green-beans, browning

My bush bean leaves are getting these brown spots, and I can’t quite figure out what’s wrong with them. It doesn’t look like bean rust, and there aren’t any aphids that I can see. I water them every day so they are getting enough water. Thank you for your help! [image]